# Attempting to compile with cmake

Tags: c++, qt

I'm attempting to compile a program with dependencies in Cmake and Qt (on Mountain Lion). The code

```
cmake build
```

returns

```
CMake Error at /Applications/CMake 2.8-12.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1386 (message):
 Found unsuitable Qt version "" from NOTFOUND, this code requires Qt 4.x
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:195 (FIND_PACKAGE)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

The current Qt version is 5.1.1, which I have installed in ~/bin/ and I'm not sure how to get Cmake to find it.

Comment: The cmake files and probably also the source code require Qt4 and won't work with Qt5 out of the box. Both source and cmake will need porting to work with Qt5.

Answer (score 2):

The error is saying `this code requires Qt 4.x` then for what are you wandering? it is due to line FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4 REQUIRED) though Cmake version should support Qt5 but may be your CmakeList is not proper written for that. 
Follow [this](http://qt.developpez.com/doc/5.0-snapshot/cmake-manual/) document to correct your CmakeList.

Comment: One should note that the source code might also require porting.